# VMWare Fusion Bridged Mode cannot access the Internet (Destination Host Unreachable)

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, centos, ping, vmware-fusion

I got a confusing issue when trying to configure the network settings for my VMWare Fusion virtual machines.

My guest machine and host machine can ping each other, but my guest machine cannot connect to the Internet. For example, when I was pinging [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), it returns:

```
PING www.google.com (31.13.81.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.124.15 (192.168.124.15) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.124.15 (192.168.124.15) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.124.15 (192.168.124.15) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.124.15 (192.168.124.15) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4003ms
pipe 4
```

Also, I cannot access any website using my default FireFox browser.

Additional Information:

- My host machine can access Internet.
- I am using macOS Catalina as my host and CentOS 7 as my guest.
- My guest machine is configured to use static IP address.
- After changing the network settings, I have rebooted to make any changes take effect.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.